# Transforming a nested sort loop in python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, underscore.js

I'm trying to convert a sort and loop from python into javascript and can't figure it out :(

```
G = {
 0: {0: 100000, 1: 294, 2: 366},
 1: {0: 294, 1: 100000, 2: 140},
 2: {0: 366, 1: 140, 2: 100000}
}
```

I have this for loop in python:

```
for W,u,v in sorted((G[u][v], u, v) for u in G for v in G[u]):
```

And want to convert into javascript (using underscore if necessary), and add magic so that it turns into this:

```
var y = [
[140, 1, 2),
[140, 2, 1],
[294, 0, 1],
[294, 1, 0],
[366, 0, 2],
[366, 2, 0],
[100000, 0, 0],
[100000, 1, 1],
[100000, 2, 2]]
```

I have been able to get a list of the results in an array using two `for in` loops:

```
for (u in x) {
    for (v in x[u]) {
        console.log([x[u][v], u, v])
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
[100000, "0", "0"]
[294, "0", "1"]
[366, "0", "2"]
[294, "1", "0"]
[100000, "1", "1"]
[140, "1", "2"]
[366, "2", "0"]
[140, "2", "1"]
[100000, "2", "2"]
```

But now I'm trying to get those arrays to be sorted by index 0 and 1 I believe.

Comment: Show us what you have tried otherwise it just appears that you expect others to write this all for you. The objective here is to help fix *your code* attempts to solve your issue...not to be a free code conversion or writing service

Comment: the output that you showed isn't valid js. you could put an array of arrays though...

Comment: At least try creating the array....then sort once you get the first step done

Comment: maybe this: result.sort((a1, a2) => a1[1] - a2[1]).sort((a1, a2) => a1[0] - a2[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the object and build arrays by taking the keys an indices and then get the values as well as the indices. Then sort the array by the values at first second and third index.

```js
var g = { 0: { 0: 100000, 1: 294, 2: 366 }, 1: { 0: 294, 1: 100000, 2: 140 }, 2: { 0: 366, 1: 140, 2: 100000 } },
    result = Object
        .assign([], g)
        .reduce((r, o, i) => {
            Object.assign([], o).forEach((v, j) => r.push([v, i, j]));
            return r;
        }, [])
        .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do it actually:

```js
const original = {
 0: {0: 100000, 1: 294, 2: 366},
 1: {0: 294, 1: 100000, 2: 140},
 2: {0: 366, 1: 140, 2: 100000}
}
const result = []
for (u in original) {
    for (v in original[u]) {
        result.push([original[u][v], u, v])
    }
}
result.sort((a1, a2) => a1[1] - a2[1]).sort((a1, a2) => a1[0] - a2[0])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You can do it in a single sort: `result.sort((a1, a2) => a1[0] - a2[0] || a1[1] - a2[1])`. Also, add a let or const before `u` and `v`. Otherwise, they will be created as globals `const u in original`